# Is Docker Get Started Docs missed?

Tags: docker

I follow tutorial [Docker Get started Docs](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) step by step. But when I run : `docker build -t getting-started .` it show error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.659MB
Error response from daemon: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

I wanted to give up because I couldn't find any answers online. But like a miracle, when I right click on DockerFile, it shows me an option "Build image" (thanks to Visual Studio Code) and it actually runs : `docker build --pull --rm -f "DockerFile" -t app:latest "."`  and then works well. I don't know if there is my mistake somewhere or this is docker docs mistake?

Comment: From which directory are you running this command...??

Comment: it's convention is Dockerfile not DockerFile, -f argument can be used for any filename

Comment: you can try after renaming or just use -f DockerFile

Comment: @SiddiqueAhmad Exactly! I named the file wrong. Thank you so much.

Comment: glad to know that it worked